# CSV total data and list count equivalence (C#)

Tags: c#, list, csv

I have standard code that reads a csv file full of data that was obtained by reading data from a load cell. I get that data read it. And put each column into a list. The CSV file has a column length of about 118,000 but my list is only 14365. Why might be happening?

Here is my code - class of readings:

```
public class ReadingClassSample 
{
    public double Time;
    public double Ax; 
    public double Ay; 
    public double Az;
    public double Bx; 
    public double By; 
    public double Bz:
    public double Cx; 
    public double Cy; 
    public double Cz;
    public double Dx; 
    public double Dy; 
    public double Dz:

    public ReadingClassSample()
    {}

    public ReadingClassSample(string[] vals)
    {
        try
        {
            Double.TryParse(vals[0], out Time);
            Double.TryParse(vals[1], out Ax);
            Double.TryParse(vals[2], out Ay); 
            Double.TryParse(vals[3], out Az); 
            Double.TryParse(vals[6], out Bx); 
            Double.TryParse(vals[5], out By); 
            Double.TryParse(vals[6], out Bz);
            Double.TryParse(vals[7], out Cx);
            Double.TryParse(vals[8], out Cy);
            Double.TryParse(vals[9], out Cz);
            Double.TryParse(vals[10], out Dx);
            Double.TryParse(vals[11], out Dy);
            Double.TryParse(vals[12], out Dz);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error parsing the data into a double.")
        }
    }
}
```

CSV File Reader Code

```
public void ReadLCCSVFile(string samplePath)
{
        StreamReader sampleReader;

        List<ReadingClassSample> lcOutputList = new List<ReadingClassSample>();

        List<double> AxList = new List<double>();
        List<double> AyList = new List<double>();
        List<double> AzList = new List<double>();
        List<double> BxList = new List<double>();
        List<double> ByList = new List<double>();
        List<double> BzList = new List<double>();
        List<double> CxList = new List<double>();
        List<double> CyList = new List<double>();
        List<double> CzList = new List<double>();
        List<double> DxList = new List<double>();
        List<double> DyList = new List<double>();
        List<double> DzList = new List<double>();

        if (File.Exists(samplePath))
        {
            sampleReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(samplePath));

            while (!sampleReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = sampleReader.ReadLine();
                string[] values = line.Split(',');

                ReadingClassSample temp = new ReadingClassSample(values);

                sampleOutputList.Add(temp);
            }
          
                AxList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Ax);
                AyList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Ay);
                AzList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Az);
                BxList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Bx);
                ByList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].By);
                BzList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Bz);
                CxList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Cx);
                CyList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Cy);
                CzList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Cz);
                DxList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Dx);
                DyList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Dy);
                DzList.Add(sampleOutputList[ii].Dz);

            SampleAxList = AxList;
            SampleAyList = AyList;
            SampleAzList = AzList;
            SampleBxList = BxList;
            SampleByList = ByList;
            SampleBzList = BzList;
            SampleCxList = CxList;
            SampleCyList = CyList;
            SampleCzList = CzList;
            SampleDxList = DxList;
            SampleDyList = DyList;
            SampleDzList = DzList;
        }
}
```

TLDR: when I check the CSV file its has usually over 118,000 values in a column but my code only takes 14,000 - 16,000 for some reason.

Comment: I recommend don't use `EndOfStream`, StreamReader buffers the readings. Use instead `string line=null; while((line=sampleReader.ReadLine())!=null)`

Comment: @Magnetron Well, that actually worked. So, let me get this straight. SteamReader Buffers the readings and for some reason that doesn't give me all the values? I am trying to understand why I was having this issue. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: `StreamReader` reads an `X` amount of byte from the underlining stream and put it in his buffer. The stream position will be after the bytes read, but that is not the position where you already have read. `StreamReader` does that for performance reasons, and because it deals with text, not bytes (Enconding might use many bytes for a single character) so it's fast for methods like `ReadLine`. So, avoid dealing direct with the underlining stream (like Seek, Position and EndofStream). `StreamWriter` is similar, that's why it has to flush the data (transfer from buffer to stream)

Comment: Putting each column in it's own list is rarely the right approach. It's FAR more common to have **one** list to hold an object with properties for each column, and with good reason.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Could you provide and example please?

Comment: Also, I'd like to mention that the code looks inconsistent because I made changes from the original code when I put it on Stack. Sorry, if that confuses anyone.

Answer (score 1):

`StreamReader` reads an X amount of bytes from the underlining stream and put it in his internal buffer. The stream position will be after the bytes read, but that is not the position where you already have read, that depends on what in the buffer you have already read. So, avoid dealing direct with the underlining stream (like `Seek`, `Position` and `EndofStream`), because that's not the position where you actually are. `StreamWriter` is similar, that's why it has to flush the data (transfer from buffer to stream).

So, instead of

```
while (!sampleReader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = sampleReader.ReadLine();
```

use

```
string line = null;
while ((line = sampleReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
```

Since `ReadLine` and `Read` consumes from the buffer.